# Does bounty reward offered to the first answer or first edited answer

Tags: support

In a question, if Answer A is the first answer but has been edited after Answer B has been posted. To which answer the bounty reward goes after the Grace period?

Comment: It has mentioned "oldest answer is awarded the bounty" but in this case which one?

Comment: An edit does not make an answer any newer AFAIK

Comment: The linked faq says "If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), **the oldest answer** is awarded the bounty". Oldest takes into account only the time of posting, so edit in this case is not relevant. (and answer A will be given half the bounty using your example)